# C# - MYSQL - how to auto update age inside database

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-update

For example, I have a table including Name, Age, and Birthday columns. Is it possible in C# to auto-update every age when it's their birthday? Please provide me some sample codes, I really need it now to pass my course. I don't have any idea on how to do this.

Comment: Use View/generated(computed) column

Comment: Will it update the age inside the database too?

Comment: As a general rule it is never advisable to store data that is dependent on the current date in the database but calculate it on the fly whenever it is needed. So in your case store only the Name and Birthday, then calculate the Age whenever data is retrieved from the database either through a view (database) or in your Persistence layer (code).

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is probably to use a database view where you calculate the age of the person dynamically every time it's fetched. This way you don't even need to store the age of the person in the database, since it can be calculated from the birthdate.

```
CREATE VIEW PersonView AS
SELECT Name, 
       Birthday, 
       TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,Birthday,CURDATE()) as Age
FROM PersonTable
```

Comment: i added `TIMESTAMPDIFF` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff feel free to roll back

Comment: Why do I get only null values when I use the code to get the age?

Comment: Did you add this view to your mysql database?

Comment: And age contains null, if you make a select on this view?

Comment: Yes, why is it happening?

Comment: It's probably very difficult to tell without seeing your actual table and the data contained within it.

Comment: What type are they? String or Date?

Comment: You should allways store your dates as a Date in the datebase, you can then in the program make the conversion to a format like "March 22, 1997".

Answer (score 0):

You should use timestampt in order to do this

Check below link

[How to use timestampt](https://www.marcus-povey.co.uk/2013/03/11/automatic-create-and-modified-timestamps-in-mysql/)